# How to call the previous querystring parameter in .aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, query-string

Let's say I have a ActionResult method that has a pageNumber parameter and a category parameter.

The user should be able to set the category he's browsing which would be a ActionLink to the first page of that category. However if I have an another ActionLink where I go to the next page the category parameter would go back to default.

How can I set the category parameter to be the same as on the previous page.

EDIT: Originally supposed to be a comment, but grow in size

Sorry, I see my question isn't clear enough wrote it in a kind of hurry. I'm kinda trying to do what you are doing but instead of setting the category as 1 I wan't it set as the parameter was when this page was loaded.

Scenario: I am browsing the website and click "shoes" (categoryID = 3) wich has this actionlink

 `<%=Html.ActionLink("Shoes", "Index", new { categoryID = 3 }) %>`

I get the first page of shoes and then I wan't to skip to the next page which has a actionlink

`<%=Html.ActionLink(">>>", "Index", new { page = model.currentPage + 1 }) %>`

I can't include categoryID parameter in this actionlink code because in my generic view code I of course don't know which category is active.

So when I click on that it switches to the default category again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add the category id as a property of your model object so it is available in the view.  So your view code would look like this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(">>>", "Index", new { categoryId = model.categoryId, page = model.currentPage + 1 }) %>
```

Comment: I see my question wasn't clear enough so I added a little. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was with storing parameters between calls as the Page parameter wasn't related to the Category parameter and would always be added seperatly and then I lost the value of the other. For example here:

```
    public ActionResult Products(int? page, int? category)
    {
        var result = repo.GetAllProductsByCategory(category);

        result.Skip(PAGE_SIZE * (page -1)).Take(PAGE_SIZE)

        return View(result);
    }
```

Inside the .aspx in pseudocode

`actionlink ("Shoes", "Products", new { category = 2 })
actionlink ("Pants", "Products", new { category = 3 })
actionlink ("Hats", "Products", new { category = 4 })`

"foreach code shows first page"

actionlink ("next page", Products, new { page = lala.nextPage })

Here when I click next page the category choosen is lost because it only throws in the parameter for the Page Number.

I myself finally used Ajax and partialViews to fix this but I also figured another simple way that would probably work. Just store the last category choosen in the controller as a variable. Like this:

```
    public ActionResult Products(int? page, int? category)
    {
        m_category = category;

        var result = repo.GetAllProductsByCategory(m_category);

        result.Skip(PAGE_SIZE * (page -1)).Take(PAGE_SIZE)

        return View(result);
    }
```

This way we won't forget what category the user was browsing when he turns the page. It still needs some implementing as for example how to null it again if the user was browsing through all products instead of a particular category ( actionlink where new category = null perhaps).

Comment: I could have also stored it in ViewData.